# call REST-API from AsynchTask in another class

Tags: android

When I call the REST-API from the AynchTask which is defined as private in the same class as the activity(as an inner class of the activity), it works.

Here's the code:

```
    protected String doInBackground(String... params){
        EditText user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enter_username);
        EditText pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enter_password);
        String username = user.getText().toString();
        String password = pass.getText().toString();
        String message = null;

        HttpClient httpClient = ServiceHelper.getHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://test.gogch.com/gch-restful/login");
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",username));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password));
        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            Log.d("Http Post Response:" ,Integer.toString(statusCode));
            message = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            Log.d("Http Post Response:" ,message);

        }
        catch(ClientProtocolException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return message;
    }
```

But when the same Asynch is defined as a new class its not working. Here's the code.

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    Log.d("doINSTARTED","Success");
    String username = params[1].toString();
    String password = params[2].toString();
    String message = null;
    Log.d("TAG","username:" + username + " password:" + password);
    HttpClient httpClient = ServiceHelper.getHttpClient();
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://test.gogch.com/gch-restful/login");
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",username));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password));
    Log.d("TAG","WORKING123");
    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        Log.d("TAG","YES");
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        Log.d("TAG","STILL WORKING");
        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        Log.d("Http Post Response:" ,Integer.toString(statusCode));
        message = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        Log.d("Http Post Response:" ,message);

    }
    catch(ClientProtocolException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return message;
}
```

This is what the log says.

04-02 13:10:09.761  30250-30307/com.cinch.getvitalsapp W/System.err﹕ java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "test.gogch.com": No address associated with hostname

How can it be? It was working when I defined the AsycMethod in the same class. I connected to the server and got the response text.

```
04-03 00:19:17.935    4910-4910/com.cinch.getvitalsapp I/art﹕ Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
04-03 00:19:18.241    4910-4928/com.cinch.getvitalsapp D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
04-03 00:19:18.250    4910-4910/com.cinch.getvitalsapp D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
04-03 00:19:18.354    4910-4928/com.cinch.getvitalsapp I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: QUALCOMM Build: 10/28/14, c33033c, Ia6306ec328
04-03 00:19:18.355    4910-4928/com.cinch.getvitalsapp I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-03 00:19:18.377    4910-4928/com.cinch.getvitalsapp D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
04-03 00:19:29.119    4910-5046/com.cinch.getvitalsapp D/doINSTARTED﹕ Success
04-03 00:19:29.124    4910-5046/com.cinch.getvitalsapp D/TAG﹕ username:okay password:okay
04-03 00:19:29.138    4910-5046/com.cinch.getvitalsapp D/TAG﹕ WORKING123
04-03 00:19:29.143    4910-5046/com.cinch.getvitalsapp D/TAG﹕ YES
    --------- beginning of crash
04-03 00:19:29.173    4910-5046/com.cinch.getvitalsapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
    Process: com.cinch.getvitalsapp, PID: 4910
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:451)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
            at com.cinch.getvitalsapp.services.PostLoginData.doInBackground(PostLoginData.java:67)
            at com.cinch.getvitalsapp.services.PostLoginData.doInBackground(PostLoginData.java:35)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
            at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:438)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
            at com.cinch.getvitalsapp.services.PostLoginData.doInBackground(PostLoginData.java:67)
            at com.cinch.getvitalsapp.services.PostLoginData.doInBackground(PostLoginData.java:35)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
            at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:438)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
            at com.cinch.getvitalsapp.services.PostLoginData.doInBackground(PostLoginData.java:67)
            at com.cinch.getvitalsapp.services.PostLoginData.doInBackground(PostLoginData.java:35)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
04-03 00:19:29.460    4910-4928/com.cinch.getvitalsapp D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ endAllStagingAnimators on 0xb80f5cf0 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xb8139ac8
04-03 00:19:32.157    4910-5046/com.cinch.getvitalsapp I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 4910 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Show your full logcat for the error - something else is wrong. Also, I don't believe your first code block can work as you say - the following line (for example) `String username = user.getText().toString();` will throw an exception as you are trying to access the text of an `EditText` (owned by the main thread) from `doInBackground` which runs on a separate thread. That is not possible.

Comment: First code works fine, I just checked. For first code, AsyncTask is defined as an inner class of the activity class

Comment: I've added log to the post. please check

Comment: OK, I take it back - you're instantiating new `EditText` objects in `doInBackground` which is why it works (although that still isn't good practice). Looking at the logcat - the answer is here `Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)`. What else have you changed? It's suggesting you haven't set the relevant `<uses-permission>` element in `AndroidManifest.xml` to allow you to access the Internet

Comment: yes, that was the problem, thank you

Comment: can you tell me which is the better practice? define AsyncTask in a new class or same class as the activity

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. As for `AsyncTask` as an inner class or as a standalone class is concerned, there's no right answer. Creating them as inner classes is more convenient but you may end up repeating code if you need similar `AsyncTask` operations in different `Activities`. There are also complications if the device is rotated and the `Activity` is destroyed / recreated. Using a standalone `AsyncTask` also has its complications as the the UI methods (e.g., onPostExecute(...)) need access to the UI components and the `AsyncTask` needs to be detached/re-attached on configuration change.